# How to I bind EXCEL range in VBA macro from a C# Library that returns object[,]

Tags: c#, vba, excel-interop

I have a C# library which has 2 methods. One returns an Integer and another returns a object[,]

```
public int ReturnInt()
{
    //Something that return INT
}
public object[,] Return2DArray()
{
    //returns twoDimensionalArrayResponse;
}
```

Now I am very new to VBA and due to some legacy reasons I need to write a VBA macro rather than VSTO excel Addin to call this Library.

Getting the result from the first meathod was easy. I made the assembly com visible and registered it for Com Interop and then added it as a reference in my VBA project and called it using the code below

```
Sub GXSData()
    Dim InteropClass As New ExcelInterOpWrapper
    Dim result As Integer
    result = InteropClass.ReturnInt()
    MsgBox "Rows Returned =" & CStr(result)
End Sub
```

So far , so good. Now I want to call the second method get the data and bind it to excel.

Sounds simple but 
--> What type should I use to hold this data. I tried Dynamic array and it did not work
--> How do I bind it to a dynamic range. Let's say the 2d array is 100*10 I want to bind it to a range something like `Range.value = Array` I know how to do this in excel addin application in C# but VBA is giving me real problems

Any help on this will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this . It is not the perfect approach but works for me for now. Due to my C# skills I wrote the function that will write in excel in C# and simply called it in VBA macro. I am sure there are pure macro ways of doing this , which I would like. This is because I am writing this as an API and MACRO clients will be calling my API. So I would like to have presentation layer in macro. But anyway the C# is here in case it is useful to someone
The C# method

```
public static void BindDataToExcel( Excel.Range range,  object[,] response)
          {
              int rows = response.GetLength(0);
              int cols = response.GetLength(1);
              int n = 0;
              Excel.Range newRange = range.get_Offset(n, 0).get_Resize(rows - n, cols);
              newRange.Value = response;
          }
```

My Macro

```
Sub GxsData()
    Dim InteropClass As New ExcelInterOpWrapper 
    Dim o As Object
    Set o = InteropClass.BindDataToExcel(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```